# UnableToMigrateException: The selected target store format 'AF4.3.0' (introduced in 4.3.0) is no longer supported

Tags: java, database, neo4j, linkurious

I am trying to upgrade Neo4J from version 4.4.4 to 5.8.0 but getting below Exception:

> UnableToMigrateException: The selected target store format 'AF4.3.0'
> (introduced in 4.3.0) is no longer supported

How do I resolve this? Can anyone please help me!

Comment: You may want to submit a [neo4j issue](https://github.com/neo4j/neo4j/issues) for this.

Comment: @cybersam Created a new issue: https://github.com/neo4j/neo4j/issues/13217

Comment: This issue is resolved now- https://github.com/neo4j/neo4j/issues/13217 Solution is available here.

Comment: You should [create an answer with the solution](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When migrating the database should be very careful to migrate to the requested target store format.

**This is for v5.8.0 release:**

To check the storeformat version run the database info check cmd `$neo4j/bin/neo4j-admin database info YOUR_DB_NAME_HERE`

For Example **I'm migrating from v4.4.4 to v5.8.0** It will give below:

Database name:               YOUR_DB_NAME
Database in use:              false
Store format version:         record-standard-0.1

> Store format introduced in:   4.3.0
> **Store format superseded in:   5.0.0**

Last committed transaction id:15234
Store needs recovery:         false

Store format superseded - Shows the required target store format.

To update the store format run: `$neo4j/bin/neo4j-admin database migrate --force-btree-indexes-to-range YOUR_DB_NAME_HERE`

After this check whether store format is updated or not with database info check cmd It should show below:

Database name:                neo4j
Database in use:              false
Store format version:         record-standard-1.1
**Store format introduced in:   5.0.0**
Last committed transaction id:15235
Store needs recovery:         false

The same migration is to be done to the system folder database ($neo4j...data/databases/system) as well - Don't forget to do this.

**For migration both the databases in data/databases has to be migrated for successful upgradation.**

Hope this solution works for others too! I will be glad if it helped.

Comment: Even tho I had removed the btree indexes prior to database dump, neo4j-admin database migrate YOUR_DB_NAME_HERE kept stating it had completed successfully but it had never worked whenever I checked database info.

Including the btree option finally worked for me: --force-btree-indexes-to-range

Thank you!